# React, undetermined JSX contents error on JSX component inside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

here is my code which is suppose to toggle between to components

```js
class DateComponent extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isHidden: true
    }
  }
  toggleHidden () {
    this.setState({
      isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    })
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.isHidden &&  <DateNormalComponent />}</div>
        <div>{!this.state.isHidden && <DateEditComponent />}</div>
      <div>
    )
  }
}
const DateEditComponent = () => (
  <div>something editable</div>
)
const DateNormalComponent = () => (
  <div>something</div>
)

// export default DateComponent;
ReactDOM.render(
  <DateComponent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

On inside both functions where I have the JSX elements that are suppose to render, I get this error on  `<div>something editable</div>` I'm following this tutorial: https://eddyerburgh.me/toggle-visibility-with-react

Comment: Could you please show the error.

Comment: you're missing a closing `</div>` in `render`. just change the last `<div>` into `</div>`.

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-in-future. It's just a typo after the two lines with the components, you have `<div>` instead of `</div>` to close that.

Comment: @Daniel thanks I noticed my typo

Comment: @Sim: Since it's just a typo, you should delete the question.